# How to change number of pixels to support different screen densities

Tags: android, android-image

I've read that it's good practice to provide images of different sizes in  Android app development, to account for different pixel densities.

My question is: how can I accomplish this?

Should I find the image I want and just resize it (using, for example, something like Microsoft Paint)?

Or am I getting this wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Follow the documentation, create multiple resources is a right approach.[Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Android support `scaleType` attributes to help you scale your `ImageView` (default is `CenterCrop`)

Beside of that, there is a library that could help you support all screens in Android [SDP Github](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

Comment: Thank you, but what I mean is, how can create multiple images of different sizes from the image I want to include in the app? How do I actually change the size of the image before uploading it to the app?

Comment: Use tool like Sketch to export 1x,2x,3x,4x.. follow right ratio of android. 36x36 (0.75x) for low-density
48x48 (1.0x baseline) for medium-density
72x72 (1.5x) for high-density
96x96 (2.0x) for extra-high-density
144x144 (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density
192x192 (4.0x) for extra-extra-extra-high-density

Comment: Can I do the same with Microsoft Paint?

Comment: Photoshop, AI, Sketch for better productivity. But sure, depend on you.